# inner loops, procedure call confusion

Tags: vb.net

So what the issue is, i have 2 for loops one nested within another. The outer loop calling a procedure, the inner loop setting a attribute for the procedure to use. The problem is that the procedure is that I wan't to exit the loop use the pos <-- attribute call the procedure and re-enter the inner loop. At the minute the pos is only being set once because all the conditions are true within the inner loop meaning that its being replaced each time. I want to be able to set the pos exit the inner loop, call the procedure and re-enter the inner loop and set it pos to a different value? any help would be great!! here is the code

```
 For Each val As String In vals


        If creditPoints = "20" And semester = "1" And year = "Year 1" Then

            For Each position In MyPosList

                If position.strLabel = "a1" And available(0) <> "False" Then
                    pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                    count += 1
                    available(0) = blnavailable
                ElseIf position.strLabel = "b1" And available(1) <> "False" Then
                    pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                    count += 1
                    available(1) = blnavailable               
Next
 shortfat(semester, pos, creditPoints, title, year, modStatus, count)
        End If
next
```

Comment: too much code, please write a shorter example.

Comment: Why not call the procedure in the inner loop?

Comment: it can't compile, `next` is out of the `if` statement. not clear what you want.

Comment: Not clear. Please be clear in the explanation. what is the condition with pos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking to break out of the inner loop when one of those conditions are met? If so, that's what the `Exit` keyword is for. You really should also set a flag to sanity check yourself, too.

```
''//Flag so that we know if we actually found a position
Dim FoundPosition as Boolean
For Each val As String In vals
    ''//Reset the flag and assume that are conditions are met
    FoundPosition = False
    If creditPoints = "20" And semester = "1" And year = "Year 1" Then
        For Each position In MyPosList
            If position.strLabel = "a1" And available(0) <> "False" Then
                pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                count += 1
                available(0) = blnavailable
                ''//Flag that our conditions are met
                FoundPosition = True
                ''//Exit from the inner loop
                Exit For
            ElseIf position.strLabel = "b1" And available(1) <> "False" Then
                pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                count += 1
                available(1) = blnavailable
                ''//Flag that our conditions are met
                FoundPosition = True
                ''//Exit from the inner loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ''//Sanity check to ensure that our conditions are met
        If FoundPosition Then
            shortfat(semester, pos, creditPoints, title, year, modStatus, count)
        Else
            ''//Do something here, either Throw an error or safely handle this case otherwise
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is there any way i can exit the loop using a boolean? so like within the if, if found position is set to true then stop looping?

Comment: @Stefan Reaney, I don't know what you mean. `Exit For` is how you break out of a loop early. You can do it under an condition you want, so if you want to check a Boolean, go for it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to be able to set the pos exit the inner loop, call the
>   procedure and re-enter the inner loop and set it pos to a different
>   value?"

Things like that are better served with a WHILE loop than a FOR loop.

Just a stab in the dark here, but it sounds like you want to be able to see if **shortfat** is producing a favorable value.  And if it does not, you want it to recompute **pos**.  The first thing I'd do, is alter **shortfat** to return some kind of value...for my example, I'll have it return a boolean.

```
    Dim blnDidThisDoWhatIWant As Boolean

    For Each val As String In vals
        If creditPoints = "20" And semester = "1" And Year() = "Year 1" Then
            blnDidThisDoWhatIWant = False

            While blnDidThisDoWhatIWant = False
                For Each position In MyPosList
                    If position.strLabel = "a1" And available(0) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        count += 1
                        available(0) = blnavailable
                    ElseIf position.strLabel = "b1" And available(1) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        count += 1
                        available(1) = blnavailable
                    End If
                Next

                blnDidThisDoWhatIWant = shortfat(semester, pos, creditPoints, title, Year, modStatus, count)
            End While
        End If
    Next
```

This will allow you to re-enter the inner loop.  The problem is that it'll be infinite unless **pos** is computed differently (which I don't see how it can).  So that's something you'll have to work out on your own.  Hope this helps point you in the right direction.